# How to exclude from selection an empty cell?

Tags: postgresql

I mean that in a column there are numbers, [NULL], and empty cell - how to exclude it from the output?
The column looks like that:

```
|123   |
|23,45 |
|      |
|5,67  |
|1,06  |
|[NULL]|
```

Using expression

```
SELECT column from scheme.table1...,
```

how I can get the output like that:

```
123,
23,45 
5,67
1,06
[NULL]
```

Comment: `where the_column is not null`?

Comment: No, I want to see [NULL]  in the output. I don't want to see the empty cells)

Comment: The string `'[NULL]'` is something different that the `NULL` value. What about `where the_column <>''` if you mean an empty string instead

Comment: You could use `COALESCE(the_column, -1)` , but the resulting type MUST still be the same ( float or decimal / numeric?)  type.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name,
It works! But I've got  not only empty cells the excluded, but [NULL] also. But if I need to exclude empty cells only?...

Answer (score 0):

Take care with **NULL / empty / 'NULL'** values - it's significantly different.

About your task - try to use combine condition, but before - check this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=21ff76442d3b6667ea6734d073083305)

Comment: if it's not difficult for you, could you pls define what (''), (NULL), ('NULL') are?
I always get it mixed up(... Thank you in advance.

Comment: '' is an empty string, NULL is an unknown value, 'NULL' is just a 4-letter word. An empty string is not equal to the NULL value, coz we can't confirm that a known value (empty value) equals something unknown (NULL value). And NULL is not equal to 'NULL' coz we can't confirm that an unknown value equals some word